# JBoss auto reconnect with database when database is restarted/disconnect

Tags: oracle, jboss

Does any version of JBoss supports auto reconnect with database when there is disconnect between database and JBoss?. I tried with the below configuration in

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <datasources>    
    <local-tx-datasource>
   <jndi-name>sampleDS</jndi-name>
   <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ip>:<databaseport>:<sip></connection-url>
    <user-name>username</user-name>
    <password>password</password>
    <valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</check-valid-connection-sql>
<failOverReadOnly>false</failOverReadOnly>
<autoReconnect>true</autoReconnect>
     <maxReconnects>50</maxReconnects>
     <initialTimeout>15</initialTimeout>
     </local-tx-datasource>
```

Comment: This is quite complex topic. Try to search something about "DCD" - `dead connection detection`, Jboss'es `ExceptionSorter` and `TCP keep-alive`. Theoretically this should be easy, but real production deployment introduce various surprises.

Comment: Which problems do you have?

Answer (score 6):

I am using jboss-eap-6.1 and its working perfectly. Modify jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file and add the following lines inside each `<xa-datasource>` tag.

```
                <validation>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>15000</background-validation-millis>
                </validation>
```

Comment: Thanks. Works for my 6.4 EAP, although inside a different tag - `<datasource>`. All three settings required.

Answer (score 1):

An example working for JBoss EAP 6.4 (based on JBoss AS 7.x) + Oracle:

```
<datasource>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
        <background-validation-millis>5000</background-validation-millis>
    </validation>
```

Unlike `select 1 from dual`, it validates connection via a vendor specific mechanism.