# jboss 6 - how to autoreconnect database?

Tags: oracle, jboss, jboss6.x

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957462/jboss-auto-reconnect-with-database-when-database-is-restarted-disconnect), my jboss 6 instalation don't have any standalone.xml file (neither 'standalone' folder). Should I create this file somewhere for it to work in jboss 6?

Or, is there another way for the dabase autoreconection?

Comment: Pheraps there are `domain` folder and `domain.xml` file

Comment: @krokodilko not... I did search in all folders and subfolders. The root folders are bin, client, common, docs, lib and server.

Comment: This seems to be nonstandard configuration. If you know the location of the server log file, then please look in the log and find the entries `jboss.server.base.dir` and `jboss.server.config.dir`.  If you do not know where the log is, see how the server is started - usually using one of scripst `standalone.bat` or `domain.bat` on windows, or `standalone.sh`/`domain.sh` on linux - there are located under `bin` subdirectory. Or ask someone who installed this server how it is configured.

Comment: Are you using JBoss AS 6? If so those directories/files do not exist in that release. Note that JBoss AS 6 and JBoss EAP 6 are different.

Comment: @krokodilko only the "..base.dir" exist, the "..config.dir" do not.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins yes, JBoss AS 6. Should I create them?

Comment: No. JBoss AS 6 uses a completely different directory and configuration structure. You'll want to look at the JBoss AS 6 documentation https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-12898.